# Python print list in tabular format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I print items in a list present in a dictionary in tabular format?

```
print('{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'.format('ID','Name','Votes','% of Total Vote'))

print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(key, value) for key, value in dct.items()))
```

I am using the above code and getting output like this. I also printed a dictionary on the first line of output.

[image: Output Image goes here]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: Instead of `value` pass `'\t'.join(value)` to `format`

Comment: better use `'{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'` also to print values

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post test as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could `'{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'` also to print rows with values.

```
'{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'.format(key, *value)
```

You can even assign pattern to variable to simply replace it

```
dct = {1: ['ankit', 32, 37], 2:['asfkjld', 54, 62]}

pattern = '{:>0}{:>10}{:>10}{:>20}'       

print(pattern.format('ID','Name','Votes','% of Total Vote'))

for key, value in dct.items():
    print(pattern.format(key, *value))
```

Result:

```
ID      Name     Votes     % of Total Vote
1     ankit        32                  37
2   asfkjld        54                  62
```

---

For something more complex you could use special modules.

---

Or you could keep it as `pandas.DataFrame` because it has many useful functions.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dct = {1: ['ankit', 32, 37], 2:['asfkjld', 54, 62]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index')
df.columns = ['Name','Votes','% of Total Vote']

# --- display text ---

print(df)

print('---')
print('Total Votes:', df['Votes'].sum())
print('Total   %  :', df['% of Total Vote'].sum())

# --- display plot ---

df.plot.bar(x='Name')
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
      Name  Votes  % of Total Vote
1    ankit     32               37
2  asfkjld     54               62
---
Total Votes: 86
Total   %  : 99
```

[image]